# Trying my backend project to dockerize basically but not been able to make the node server interact with the DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    postgres:
        container_name: postgres
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ****
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: ****            
        ports: 
            - '5432:5432' 
    app: 
        container_name: node-postgres
        restart: always
        build: . 
        depends_on: 
            - postgres       
        links: 
            - postgres
        ports: 
            - '5000:5000'
```

When I make a request:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With docker-compose a container network gets generated (typically `myapp_default`) even if you don't specify one, all of the containers within the compose file are then run on that network. This means that when the containers are calling `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it's not the correct address for the container within the container network.

The good thing about this is that you can communicate between containers by using the container hostname, that is the name of the container as specified within the compose file.

The solution here should be to go into your API code and change the hostname used within the db connection string to the name of the database container: e.g. from `postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432` to `postgresql://node-postgres:5432`

Read more about docker-compose networking [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: @subhadip dutta, Just a side note to this answer that should solve your problem: the `links` option is deprecated - containers can be discovered by name/service automatically...and second: usually you do not want to expose the database to the outside world, so you might also want to get rid of the `ports: '5432:5432'` from your compose file if you don't explicitly need to access it from the outside of the docker bridge network.